# SQL Update from another select

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to update a table (Oracle) from the results of another (too long and complex) query.

For simplicity, Query1 is my complex query and returns something like this:

```
 Item_ID | Item_Data
 --------------------
 10          XXX
 20          ZZZZ
 30          SSSS
```

i want to do this

```
 UPDATE MyTable SET MyTable.MyData = Query1.Item_Data where MyTable.MyID = Query1.Item_ID
```

How can i achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the MERGE INTO clause. I can't test this right now but it should be something like this:

```
MERGE INTO mytable mt
USING (your complex query here) cc
  ON mt.myid = cc.item_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET mt.mydata = cc.item_data
```

Comment: unfortunaetly i am getting this error: [Mercury][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-29886: feature not supported for domain indexes

Comment: From what I've read, that's a limitation with tables that contain domain indexes. Another option would be an UPDATE of the type 'UPDATE mytable mt SET mydata = (SELECT itemdata FROM (complex query here) WHERE item_id = my.myid)'.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, although it is VERY slow. i think i will have to go to do it programatically with a for loop